# Treat file as .HTML

Tags: html, file, .htaccess

There seems to be a lot of documentation about how to configure a browser to treat a custom file extension as a PHP file (using .htaccess), however I am aware that the same is possible for HTML.

How would I configure .htaccess to treat a file with any extension, i.e. "file.fi" as an HTML file when accessed by a browser?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`AddType` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype).

```
AddType text/html .fi
```

(I'd recommend against it on the "Don't be cute" principle, non-standard file extensions on URLs are likely to confuse at least some people)